# Convert razor view into pdf file

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, itext

I have an application where admin can user order details in an email after its completed in email  and copy is saved in server. I have a view "~/order/MyOrder.cshtml?id=Q5/KCbPNhXKx7EWffTprWg==" which user can see after logging in to check their status. But when order is fulfilled admin send an email to user with order status and in a pdf file with all the information. I am trying to create a pdf file from the view mention above and planning to attache that file to an email. What the best way to do this. I saw few solution's here but i am not able to figure out bet way to handle this.  I am using ITexSharp for this.

```
        string html = RenderViewToString(ControllerContext,
    "/order/MyOrder.cshtml?Auth=Q5/KCbPNhXKx7EWffTprWg==",
    model, true);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(html);
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            var Filename =  File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Grid.pdf");
            zip.AddFile(Filename.FileDownloadName, "Pdf");
        }
```

and RanderViewToString function:

```
static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context,
                            string viewPath,
                            object model = null,
                            bool partial = false)
{
    // first find the ViewEngine for this view
    ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = null;
    if (partial)
        viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewPath);
    else
        viewEngineResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(context, viewPath, null);

    if (viewEngineResult == null)
        throw new FileNotFoundException("View cannot be found.");

    // get the view and attach the model to view data
    var view = viewEngineResult.View;
    context.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;

    string result = null;

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var ctx = new ViewContext(context, view,
                                    context.Controller.ViewData,
                                    context.Controller.TempData,
                                    sw);
        view.Render(ctx, sw);
        result = sw.ToString();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am getting "Value cannot be null.Parameter name: view'" error. I am not sure how to pass the view with parameters to convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try Rotativa

https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa

```
  public ActionResult PrintIndex()
  {
          return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
   }
```